# outer function with ">=" misbehaving?

Tags: r

I'm curious if somebody can shed light on the following scenario:

```
seqA <- c(0.3, 0.47, 0.52, 0.85, 1)
seqB <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
o    <- outer(seqA, seqB, ">=")

rownames(o) <- seqA
colnames(o) <- seqB

o

        0  0.1  0.2  0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9     1
0.3  TRUE TRUE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
0.47 TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
0.52 TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
0.85 TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
1    TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you look at row 0.3 and col 0.3, why is the value `FALSE`? Given that I used `>=` in the `outer` function, I was expecting a value of `TRUE`.

Comment: This would be related to floating point

Comment: This is indeed floating-point error.  `0.1` cannot be exactly represented, so you have a very small but accumulating error in the sequence.